# SSIS + ScriptTask + Visual Basic 2015 script to get created date of FTP file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, ftp

I have an SSIS package with a `Script Task` using Microsoft Visual Basic 2015. I am trying to find out how to get the created date of a file on an FTP server using windows authentication. This is what I got from Googling but can't get it to work:

```
Dim ftp as Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(Net.FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.company.com/folder/file.txt"), Net.FtpWebRequest)
ftp.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp
Dts.Variables("test").Value = ftp.GetResponse()
```

When I execute the package, it just keeps running. In Visual Studio it just shows the yellow busy/running icon on the Script Task.

Comment: *"can't get it to work"* - That's not a problem description.

Comment: Good point @MartinPrikryl. I added a comment.

Comment: So then we need to a see a complete code: [mcve]